# How do I connect to my database without hard coding it in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I’m currently connecting to my database through my hard coding link in my config file, but I want to be able to dynamically generate this connection so I will be able to use multiple connections in the future.

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ‘postgresql+psycopg2://<blah>/database’
```

Comment: OK. So what's stopping you?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don’t know how or where to start

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#configuring-from-environment-variables

Comment: There are different ways of achieving your goal. Good starting points are here: http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/binds/ or http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/ or http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

Answer (score 1):

You could put the database connection parameters in an external file, eg `connections_settings.ini`

```
[credentials]
host=localhost
dbname=test
username=me
password=secret
```

and then read them with the `configparser` module, and create the connection url with string interpolation

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser('connection_settings')['credentials']

connection_settings = {
    'host': config['host'],
    'dbname': config['dbname'],
    'user': config['username'],
    'password': config['password']
}

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{host}/{dbname}'
```